# MySQL how to retrieve values from referenced tables?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to learn referential relations between fields in various tables and I'm having trouble figuring out the following:

If I have two tables:

1) One is for students that have name, age, id, gpa and grade.

2) One is for a teachers roll call that has the name of the class, its section number and the ids of the students attending the class.

How can I write a query similar to this pseudo:

```
         SELECT classname and sectionnumber WHERE the students in the class at least junior?
```

How do you use the field in one table to reference a value of a field in another referenced table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select a.classname, a.sectionNo
   from ClassRosert a 
   inner join Student b using(studentId)
   where b.class = 'junior';
```

Or in that case you could do

```
select a.classname, a.sectionNo
   from ClassRosert a, Student b 
   where a.studentId = b.studentId
     and b.class = 'junior';
```

But I would recommend the first one as it is more clear that you are joining table.

Notice that in the first case, I used the `using` keyword because mapping value have the same name in both table (studentId). However, if in student table it would have been called just ID or any other name, the join would have been `inner join Student b on a.studentid = b.id`

Comment: Add distinct keyword after select to avoid duplicates... `select distinct ... `